# Unable to read WCSession singleton instance of WatchConnectivity framework

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchconnectivity, wcsession

I m trying to work on WCSession default instance. But it gives the following complier issue.
[image: When I try to read as vairable]

[image: When I try to read as method]

[image: Compiler suggests as method]

Defination of default Instance
[image: When I jump to definition]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var session : WCSession!

func startSession() {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        session = WCSession.default()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}
```

Call startSession() wherever you want to activate your WCSession. Preferably in AppDelegate and ExtensionDelegate.